# Since adding slider css3 parent boxes have moved inline with it

Tags: html, css

A bit baffled here. i've added a slider transition to the portfolio box at the top, but since adding it, the two big text boxes have moved in line with it vertically when they were just sitting to the left hand side of the page beforehand. so unsure where or what has gone wrong!!

It's gonna be something small im sure, as it always is, but this is one of those little hurdles for the day which ive spent ages trying to figure out, but just cant. So hope you can help, thanks!!

[image: excuse the gradient lol, work in progress...]

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">

html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }


body {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 84% 100%, 100% 0%, from(#9179AB), to(#E39745), color-stop(.6,#B37D89))
}

div.home {
  width: 250px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #212121;
  float:left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #191919;
  border-width: 1.5px;
}

div.mentioncopy {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

div.portfolio {
  width: 125px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #212121;
  float: left;
  border-style: solid; 
  border-color: #191919;
  border-width: 1.5px;
}

div.portfoliocopy {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

div.about {
  width: 125px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #212121;
  float:left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #191919;
  border-width: 1.5px;
}

div.aboutcopy {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.sliding-middle-out {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
.sliding-middle-out:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
}

.sliding-middle-out {
 opacity: 1;
 transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.sliding-middle-out:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}



a:link
{
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited
{
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover
{
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
}
a:active
{
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
}





div.header {
  width: 506px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #212121;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.headercopy {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

div.headerlink {
  width: 506px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #212121;
}

div.linkcopy {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;

}






</style>

<title>3.0</title>

</head>

<body>

<div class="home">

  <div class="mentioncopy">
    MENTIONBENJAMIN
    </div>

</div>



<div class="portfolio">

  <div class="sliding-middle-out">

    <div class="portfoliocopy">

      <a href="portfolio.html"> PORTFOLIO </a>
      </div>

  </div

</div>

<div class="about">

  <div class="aboutcopy">
    ABOUT
    </div>

</div>

<br><br><br><br><br>

<div class="header">

  <div class="headercopy">
  It’s like hosting your first dinner party with every design— to set the mood, nourish the guests and lay the table just so, requires dexterity, innovation and passion.
  </div>

</div>

<br><br>


<div class="headerlink">

  <div class="linkcopy">
 Working between strategy and design, I find nothing more satisfying than cracking a clients puzzle of a problem in an inventive, effective way. 
  </div>

</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br>






</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a "clearfix" situation, there are various solutions to accomplish it.

[What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

**New CSS**

```
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
```

**AFTER portfolio add an empty div**

```
<div class="portfolio">

  <div class="sliding-middle-out">

    <div class="portfoliocopy">

      <a href="portfolio.html"> PORTFOLIO </a>
      </div>

  </div> <!---- this needs the greater than sign also! --->

</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: No problem, I have experienced a similar problem so many times that I simply looked for a float.